Does "the man went to the left of the building" refer to "the man's left" or "the speaker's left" or "the building's left"?

A speaker is looking at a man like the above picture. The man is facing the front of a building.
The speaker said "the man went to the left of the building".
Does the speaker refer to the area A or B (in the circles)?
Sometimes, we can not identify the front or back of a building. If the building has a front with a porch and door, does "the left of the building" is the area B?
But "the left of the man" refers to the area A and "the left of speaker" refers to the area opposite the building on the other side of the road.
Does "the man went to the left of the building" refer to "the man's left" or "the speaker's left" or "the building's left"?

There can be ambiguity in similar expressions.  Do you know the phrase "stage-left", which actors and directors use to avoid such ambiguity?


Sometimes, it may be difficult to identify the front or back of a building. If the building has a front with a porch and door, does "the left of the building" refer to Area B?

Consider this sentence:
"English is written from left to right.".
The left side of a page is the side on your left when you're facing the page directly.
Similarly, if you are standing in front of a building and looking at it, the viewer's left side is the left side of the building (Area A). This orientation remains the same, regardless of the speaker's or listener's position.
So the term "the man went to the left of the building" means "the man went to area A".


The man went to the left of the building

means he went to area A, that is, the man's left.
We generally don't treat a building facing us as having its left-right sense opposite of ours.
Edit
I add here my answer to the OP’s query in the comments.
If the man was facing another person, say a woman, the woman's left-right is the mirror image of the man's.  The left of the woman would be the right of the man.

SO, we don't care about the face of the building? Say the man is facing the side (not the front or the back) of the building, then "the man went to the left of the building" refers to his left, right?

What about "the man went to the left of the woman"? Does it refer to the man's left or the woman's left?

@Tom, to your first query, yes.  To your second, I've added my point to the answer.
